# Unknown class QuoteDetailViewController in Interface Builder file with Xcode 12

Tags: swift, xcode

I saw a lot of posts about this error in Xcode but all of them are quite old. I'm learning how to code in Swift and I'm following the instruction of book.

My Xcode is version 12.5.1. The goal of this app is to display a list of quotes (string) and when I tap on one of them, display a new view that has as a title the quote.

I have a very simple storyboard. There is a `TableView` with a `segue` to a `View`. I created a new `Cocoa` file for tableview. `TableView` is working.

[image]

I connect the TableView with the View.

[image]

I repeated the some process for the View. I added a new Cocoa file called `QuoteDetailViewController`, click on top of the view and in the **Class** I selected from the list the file.

When I run the application in the iPhone 11 simulator, the view doesn't have any quote as title. I put a breakpoint in the code connected to the TableView and the app stops there. If I put a breakpoint in the `QuoteDetailViewController` nothing happens but I see an error in the output

> 2021-08-11 19:13:17.215204+0100 QuoteApp[80238:4055489] [Storyboard] Unknown class QuoteDetailViewController in Interface Builder file.

The `QuoteDetailViewController` is very basic.

```
import UIKit

class QuoteDetailViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let quoteViewController = segue.destination as? QuoteDetailViewController {
            if let selectedQuote = sender as? String {
                quoteViewController.title = selectedQuote
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to build again and again the app. I tried to **Clean Build Folder** and build again. I tried to recreate the View and the code. After all of that, nothing changed. The error is still there.

The source code is on [GitHub](https://github.com/erossini/Swift-QuoteApp).

### Update

If I click on the arrow at the end of `Class` and just before the dropdown, Xcode opens the file I expect to be opened.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I said that in the `QuoteDetailViewController` I have this code.

```
import UIKit

class QuoteDetailViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let quoteViewController = segue.destination as? QuoteDetailViewController {
            if let selectedQuote = sender as? String {
                quoteViewController.title = selectedQuote
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error was that the function `prepare` must be in the `QuoteTableViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

- Select the `QuoteDetailViewController`, open Side Inspector view and Update the `Target Membership` same as `QuoteTableViewController`
- Select the controller On the Storyboard, and Add it to the module.

Check Screenshots for reference:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I checked them and they are already set like you said. I created a new project, I followed the some steps with the some result. It seems `QuoteTableViewController` is disconnected from the View.

Comment: @Enrico It wasn't added to the Target in the repo you shared. And I don't see such errors after updating it.

Comment: Sorry, then I don't understand what I have to look at. I added an Update in the post because I'm sure I did it. In the Xcode UI, it seems connected.

Comment: @Enrico I don't see any errors on the repo. what error you're talking about ?

Comment: @Enrico 15hrs ago you pushed those change in the proj file. That fixed the issues.

Comment: Unfortunately no, I still have the same issue than before. Nothing changed

Comment: @Enrico Check this commit () - https://github.com/erossini/Swift-QuoteApp/commit/fd6928315ac103ced3f3b6b545de2673b8fc7ca9 . This fixed the issue probably, I don't see any error now.

Comment: Yes, I pushed this commit but the app still doesn't work. The image in the update is coming from this version. I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: @Enrico what issue you're facing now, can't you pass the data to the detail view or what??